# About k8s deployments spec.revisionHistoryLimit

Tags: kubernetes

Now I'm testing deployments controller on kubernetes.
With rollout, I set `spec.revisionHistoryLimit : 5` but the history comes out only 2 results.

How can I see 5 results?

yaml code :

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  revisionHistoryLimit: 5
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

steps:

```
$ kubectl rollout history deploy nginx-deployment
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
1         <none>
2         <none>
```

update again

```
$ kubectl rollout undo deploy nginx-deployment
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment rolled back
```

```
$ kubectl rollout history deploy nginx-deployment
deployment.apps/nginx-deployment
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
2         <none>
3         <none>

$ kubectl rollout undo deploy nginx-deployment --to-revision=1
error: unable to find specified revision 1 in history
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll only see 5 results if you have updated it atleast 4 times.

Steps to reproduce:

Deploy the given nginx deployment

```
❯❯❯ kubectl rollout history deploy nginx-deployment                                                                                                          
deployment.extensions/nginx-deployment 
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
1         <none>
```

update deployment

```
❯❯❯ kubectl rollout history deploy nginx-deployment                                                                                                              
deployment.extensions/nginx-deployment 
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
1         <none>
2         <none>
```

update deployment

```
❯❯❯ kubectl rollout history deploy nginx-deployment                                                                                                              
deployment.extensions/nginx-deployment 
REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
1         <none>
2         <none>
3         <none>
```

update deployment

```
❯❯❯ kubectl rollout history deploy nginx-deployment                                                                                                              
    deployment.extensions/nginx-deployment 
    REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
    1         <none>
    2         <none>
    3         <none>
    4         <none>
```

update deployment

```
❯❯❯ kubectl rollout history deploy nginx-deployment                                                                                                              deployment.extensions/nginx-deployment 
    REVISION  CHANGE-CAUSE
    1         <none>
    2         <none>
    3         <none>
    4         <none>
    5         <none>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try getting the list of replica-sets?

kubectl get rs -o wide